# Nothing in session after login

Tags: php, session, php-5.6

I try to connect to db, authenficate, if ok redirect to success page....

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

  $_SESSION['username']=$myusername;
  $_SESSION['password']=$mypassword;

  header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
  echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

In my login_success.php script i have

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

I tried with bad username, password i get "Wrong Username or Password"

If i go with good password i go to main_login.php...

It's like there are not variable in session....

Session Support is enabled

Comment: I DONT SEE A `session_start()` in the first script????? You cannot even set session data unless you start the session

Comment: plain text passwords, mysql_* = burn this and start again

Comment: @RiggsFolly is it better to put it at the beginning of the script or after if($count==1) ?

Comment: @YvanDupré Beginning, always beginning.

Comment: You might want to spend some time reading [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com). You have a lot of errors here: missing `session_start()`, using the deprecated (and removed in PHP 7) `mysql_*` functions, storing passwords in plain text, using `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of prepared statements, rolling your own security/authentication system... As @Dagon said, this is probably not salvageable.

Comment: @Nytrix to be technical only needs to be before any output.

Comment: @Dragon True. In my opinion you should just always do it on top, good practice and all. I've had some frustrating moments through that kind of small issues, like we probably all had at some point.

Comment: since if count !=1 sessions are not even used, you call unneeded functions. so i cant agree with "always" put at top. @Nytrix